# Getting "Forbidden" error while creating a meet in Teams with Microsoft Graph

Tags: node.js, azure, microsoft-teams

I want to create a meeting with API.
I created an Application in Azure Portal with this permission:

```
OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite
```

Next, I followed the OAuth flow and obtained an access token(I removed part of access to the token and copy here):

```
{
  "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/bbf86088-73dc-4587-89d3-33e6f9a1484f/",
  "name": "Meet master account",
  "oid": "90ac29be-2d4f-4e9b-a13c-b5abf8534cef",
  "platf": "5",
  "puid": "10032002F2311268",
  "scp": "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite User.Read profile openid email",
  "signin_state": [
    "kmsi"
  ],
  "sub": "KfOfRbaUEccxbfM5KfcWDjzX1gRtijFJ7Qgqw09oslU",
  "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
  "tid": "bbf86088-73dc-4587-89d3-33e6f9a1484f",
  "uti": "nQXEiowwn0SGCHPDY0IhAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
}
```

After that, I made a request like that:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "startDateTime":"2022-01-01T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2022-01-01T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
  "subject":"Test Meeting"
}
```

I got this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-09-14T09:32:46",
            "request-id": "39c6117b-7f71-43d2-bc73-c21893c0d120",
            "client-request-id": "39c6117b-7f71-43d2-bc73-c21893c0d120"
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why this error occurred.

Comment: Could you include how you are generating the access token? In my case, I used [authorization code](https://i.imgur.com/p1ttYEe.png) flow for token and created [online meeting](https://i.imgur.com/dGi2pDL.png) successfully.

Comment: @Sridevi the same way

https://i.imgur.com/7riZAaE.png
https://i.imgur.com/EuJ5OmG.png

Comment: Could you share me that user property screenshot from Portal to check user type?

Comment: Thanks! https://i.imgur.com/pUWCIFb.png

Comment: In my case, I got [**same error**](https://i.imgur.com/CSmBNy6.png) when I generated [access token](https://i.imgur.com/gAfnf2X.png) by signing in with [**guest**](https://i.imgur.com/8yewgX7.png) user account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255272/discussion-between-sridevi-and-mohammad-changani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if you are trying to create online meeting with **guest user** or user from tenant with no **`Microsoft Teams`** license in it.

I created one new tenant and registered one Azure AD application by granting **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using authorization code flow via Postman like this:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

To check **`scp`** and **`upn`** claims, I decoded the above access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website as below:

[image]

When I used this token to create online meeting, I too got **same error** as tenant has **no valid** license:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "startDateTime":"2022-01-01T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2022-01-01T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
  "subject":"Test Meeting"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, make sure to have at least one **Office 365
> license** in your tenant that includes `Microsoft Teams` in it.

When I tried the same with tenant having **proper** license, online meeting created successfully with below response:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "startDateTime":"2022-01-01T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2022-01-01T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
  "subject":"Test Meeting"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]