TeamsMeetingProcessorException
I'm trying to create online meeting  but I get an error doing so. I have an app registered on Azure Portal (free plan), which I'm using to curl request. This are the permissions I've set in order to be able to query the Microsoft Graph API:
for authorization
https://login.microsoftonline.com/0147041e-e3f7-47b7-b821-xxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=bb962351-xxx-41b7-8532-xxxxxxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345

get code successfully. Next i called token api

curl -X POST \
  'https://login.microsoftonline.com/0147041e-e3f7-47b7-b821-xxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'client_id=bb962351-xxx-41b7-8532-xxxxxxxx' \
  -d 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
  -d 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' \
  -d 'code=0.Ab4AHgRHAffjt0e4IUMRETnjJVEjlrtD3bdBhTJz3y0ap66-AKI.AgABBAIAAADnfolhJpSnRYB1SVj-Hgd8AgDs_wUA9P8c97uVUoULLvu0a73XRIPk3NR4Pux5Dv4GQJVw720mbJeeIshoy2K6NIaqTJ4vgv9VunP0s9lvtfwGCbN3lwzlAa3qjHVFF2qHzxfu19oAz1X-L3DsTeEK_4AsVHzt3jZXqC6WhiLo4N_kx-VyUZO_Uegn6SBHcaPPq3JAS1xG-oFm5csWKRLtyBZMe_VougAnknJfsOtpE3NrTNrEA3g3SPihQ1RCVIK57kngdMzSpgg6TWorknBaPNm6zvX4-vUUkExklWI4_dcnQ_XQ9Zt5AAIBzVcvd3bTD5Rr91JlH16e_PEWusxdTm92YoT_sx3Q5ETJx_BYyXVxUheR-GqGAlPFxbLSFR3N7qCjlycLHhfs8wDN8y6-9JsdROqrGntWad1cMS8wVaFvywvJyxkrvWIEZlrq6mPBegEv2Zl5KHW7_nNj2slzxpVTvit0Gu2iWRAsVwdqS59EU_2qO8SzehSlD02CBhm-U_ob-ECMNbuOmU5R4c-OPYqwCk4LhfDi8NhbO3XbImdHXIqRM-SSaB1SwFCEEMUfe-TxF9nTHZuO-gvvK_QE0QmqbAjqchXnP_ZH1Dxyu8kmb9kG01PeRuPEYac3dA' \
  -d 'redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms' \
  -d 'client_secret=T_H8Q~gYZcmFRXARYgt_cB5Np5k_xxxxxxxx'

and access_token also got successfully
step 3:
when calling onlinemeeting api getting error, i also tried users/{userid}/onlineMeetings
curl -X POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6Im5welg1d2ZCNW1hcU40bnhmRUJNQVRCTkxxTkNZVWRSVU1QOGYyRmJ3VW8iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkwxS2ZLRklfam5YYndXYzIyeFp4dzFzVUhIMCIsImtpZCI6IkwxS2ZLRklfam5YYndXYzIyeFp4dzFzVUhIMCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2dyYXBoLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20iLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3N0cy53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC8wMTQ3MDQxZS1lM2Y3LTQ3YjctYjgyMS00MzExMTEzOWUzMjUvIiwiaWF0IjoxNzE1NjIzOTAwLCJuYmYiOjE3MTU2MjM5MDAsImV4cCI6MTcxNTYyOTQyMCwiYWNjdCI6MCwiYWNyIjoiMSIsImFpbyI6IkFUUUF5LzhXQUFBQUFrcXNKNUNXV2RwbE1OK0pOS3FGa0NRcDRMK0NjaUJDTzF2eVpKUUVxbGt6WnRxRTVJ' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "startDateTime": "2024-05-14T09:00:00",
    "endDateTime": "2024-05-14T10:00:00",
    "subject": "Test Meeting"
}'

Getting error:

{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"9024: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Skype.SkypeCast.SchedulerWebRole.BusinessLogic.Teams.Common.Exceptions.TeamsMeetingProcessorException' was thrown.","innerError":{"date":"2024-05-13T18:20:35","request-id":"ce4a3ab1-c009-45d2-89ed-9fbbc21e241c","client-request-id":"ce4a3ab1-c009-45d2-89ed-9fbbc21e241c"}}}

what is issue in that? how can i solve that issue?

Could you confirm whether the user has active Office 365 license assigned or not having Microsoft Teams selected in it? Check related thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77103845/getting-forbidden-error-while-creating-a-meet-in-teams-with-microsoft-graph

@sridevi Thank you  very much , user has not active Office 365 license assigned . because i m new in that, 2 days back 1 created account and want to implement for my company. i m not able to find office 365 licence how purchase that and attach it to user, admin console not opening for me also, Request you Can you guide me how todo that

Check if this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/commerce/try-or-buy-microsoft-365?view=o365-worldwide

To resolve the error, make sure to assign active Office 365 license to the user account that includes Microsoft Teams in it.
You can follow this MS Document to know what license required and how to acquire it. After acquiring the license, make sure to assign it to the user as below:

Now, I generated the access token by signing in with user having active Office 365 license as below:
curl -X POST \
  'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'client_id=appId' \
  -d 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
  -d 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' \
  -d 'code=code' \
  -d 'redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms' \
  -d 'client_secret=secret'

Response:

When I used this token to create online meeting, I got the response successfully as below:
curl -X POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "startDateTime":"2024-05-16T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2024-05-16T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
  "subject":"Test Meeting"
}'

Response:

Reference:
Getting "Forbidden" error while creating a meet in Teams with Microsoft Graph - Stack Overflow

Work for me... Thanks.
