creating OnlineMeeting using Microsoft Graph api getting Forbidden 403 error
`In php i am trying to generate a online meeting url using microsoft teams.
We tried using the Microsoft graphs API, and were able to generate the token. However while submitting the request, we get a 403 Forbidden Error. We have registered our application in Azure and also given the required API permissions.
my API permssions also my tenant having authorized license
$auth_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
    $params = [
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
        'response_mode' => 'query',
        'scope' => 'offline_access OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite User.Read',
        'state' => '884766', // Optional: Prevent CSRF attacks
    ];

    $authUrl = $auth_url . '?' . http_build_query($params);


then in auth page
$clientId = TEAM_CLIENT_ID;
        $redirectUri = REDIRECT_URI;
        $tenantId = TENANT_ID;
        $clientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
        $tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        // Step 3: Exchange authorization code for an access token
        $client = new Client();
            $response = $client->post($tokenEndpoint, [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                    'client_id' => $clientId,
                    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
                    'code' => $authorizationCode,
                    'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
                    'scope' => 'user.read onlineMeetings.ReadWrite offline_access',
                ]
            ]);

            $responseData = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
$accessToken = $responseData['access_token'];
            $refreshToken = $responseData['refresh_token'];
            $expiresIn = $responseData['expires_in'];



untill this i am getting the response.
$response = $client->post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' .$accessToken,
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                ],
                'json' => [
                    'subject' => 'Test Meeting',
                    'startDateTime' => '2024-08-04T15:00:00Z',
                    'endDateTime' => '2024-08-04T16:00:00Z',
                ],
                'debug' => true // Enable Guzzle's debug output
            ]);


$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);



I am getting an error Guzzle HTTP error: Client error: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings resulted in a 403 Forbidden response: {"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"9024: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Skype.SkypeCast.SchedulerWebRole.BusinessLogic.Teams.Common.Exceptions.TeamsMeetingProcessorException' was thrown.. Would anyone please help out here as I am behind delivery.
`

I think this is the same question as here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78474204/teamsmeetingprocessorexception
plz check if it can help

Thank you for your response, @Bhavik. I'll check out the link you provided.

This error indicates that the user that the app is trying to create a meeting on behalf of, does not have a Teams license assigned to them. Ensure the user has a Teams license assigned to them - you can check this in the Microsoft 365 admin center.
If you rule out that the user has a Teams license assigned, double check the token to ensure it has the correct permissions-specifically OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite. Changing permissions on the portal does not automatically update the permissions of the existing access token and you may need to get a new access token after you change the permissions.
As a last resort if you have checked above, ensure that Teams is correctly set up in your tenant as you would expect the user to schedule a meeting using the Teams client and retry creating with a different user to rule out use-specific issues.
Link to relevant documentation here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

i have checked in my tenant user license i don't have Microsoft 365 license. I will do that thanks
